# What does it mean $Φ^M = Φ$, if $Φ$ is a primitive formula?

Tags: logic, model-theory

$Φ$ is a primitive formula in the language of set theory, while   $Φ^M$ is the relativisation of $Φ$ to the class $M$. I can't understand why $Φ^M = Φ$.

Let $Φ$ be $0 \in x$, it seems to me, $Φ^{\mathbb{R}} \neq Φ^{\mathbb{Z}}$, since $\{x \in   \mathbb{R}: Φ(x)\} \neq \{x \in \mathbb{Z} : Φ(x)\}$. Where has gone wrong?

Comment: By a _primitive_ formula (in the language of set theory) do you mean a formula of the form either $x \in y$ or $x = y$ (what is also called an _atomic_ formula)?

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Yes. I'm kind of confused here, because some authors equate atomic formula with primitive formula, while others don't.

Comment: $x$ is a variable...

Comment: @Arthur: Primitive formulas are those which do not yet have the control over fire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we say that the *relativisation* of a formula $\Phi$ to a class $\mathbf M$ *is* something, we mean the actual syntactic object, and not some associated classt.  Remember that the point of relativizations is to control where the quantified objects come from, and so it makes sense that for formulas *without* quantifiers, the relativization is the same as the original formula.

Given any class $\mathbf M$ the formula "$( x \in y )^{\mathbf M}$" is *defined* to be the formula "$x \in y$."  And as we move to more complicated formulas the have recursive definitions telling us how to construct the relativisation.